# How do you keep questions about beta products fresh?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, policy

Recently I was searching Google for an answer to a question I have.

I came across [what I thought would be a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796304/windows-phone-7-search-button) in Google, but it turned out the answer was a "not supported" answer, which I know isn't the case now.  And the fact the question was asked 5 months ago is a confirmation of the fact that the answer is based on a beta SDK that has changed since then.

What is the policy for keeping these types of questions fresh and relevant? They already have accepted answers and have been pretty much abandoned by the original poster, with no valid option to close or re-ask them.

So this is a policy question, in hopes that maybe a mechanism can be put in the system that allows a question to be marked as stale or based on a beta product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the answer is based on outdated information, you could edit it to say, `with the beta SDK...` (which will also bump it to the front page). The question is still the same, whether the OP has an answer or not.

Comment: This only works if you've got enough rep to change the answer. Maybe a system which converts all questions (not answers!) to CW after half a year would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new answer, explaing that your answer is now correct, giving a link to backup your answer.

I would also add a comment to the current answer to say it is talking about the beta.