# Lost consecutive days status - why was it closed?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you keep questions about beta products fresh?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/how-do-you-keep-questions-about-beta-products-fresh)
>   [How do you challenge the closing of one of your questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/how-do-you-challenge-the-closing-of-one-of-your-questions)

Due to the server outage yesterday, my consecutive days status has been reset from 98 days to 1, even though I visited StackOverflow in the morning yesterday. How do I get this status restored?

I asked this question a few hours ago and it wass closed by someone as a duplicate of: [Proposal: Free day in the visit log to account for the Oct 9th downtime](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime)

How can it be considered a duplicate when there are no answers to the other question. The other question can be considered stale if it hasn't been answered. If I still have to ask the question, is it a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, of course it's still a duplicate, even if the linked question doesn't have any answers. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/duplicate

Comment: See my comments below about the actual answer to my original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can it be considered a duplicate when there are no answers to the other question.

By that reasoning, you could ask the same question twice in a row. Just make sure to be fast enough that the first one doesn't have any answers yet when you post the second.

> The other question can be considered stale if it hasn't been answered.

The question was a whooping *20 hours* old when you asked yours. On a Sunday.

> If I still have to ask the question, is it a duplicate?

Yes.

Comment: I think that the underlying problem here is not so much what has happened, nor what response is made, but rather the fact that there is no place on SO or on Meta for a user to query their OWN status/reputation/account. Instead, a user has to post a question on Meta in the hope that their account gets looked at. If anyone has had the same issue before, it is closed as a duplicate. Maybe that is fair enough, but to avoid this, a user needs a way to get their personal situation looked at. This is the one place where I believe Meta is lacking.