# Is it okay to close questions about preview and beta products

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The BUILD conference this week (preview of Windows 8) is generating plenty of questions.

Reference question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428832/theme-resources-for-windows-8).

While generally of interest of developers, I don't care much for questions that are this speculative and inevitably become irrelevant within a year or less.  Is it okay to close them?  What close reason should be preferred?

Comment: I think the "Referenced question" is a useful question **at this time**, and does have a good answer as the SDK can be downloaded.  However it may become "too localized" over the next year.

Comment: It is funny the reference question is still relevant three years later. This hasn't changed even two versions after the release of the SDK. I certainly didn't expect it to be relevant after release.

Answer (score 17):

I think there are two different kinds of questions here:

1. concrete questions about preview- or beta-software:

   - How do I doo *foo* in Windows Developer Preview?
   - Why doesn't `frobnicate` correctly work in Android 4.0 Beta?
   - ...
2. speculative questions about preview- or beta-software:

   - How will feature *X* work in Windows 8 Beta when it is released in February?
   - What will be the default background in Android 4.0 Final?

I think #1 is fine, even if the correctness might change with time (that can happen with all software).

And #2 is bad, but not because it's about preview- or beta-software, but because it's speculative and doesn't have definite answers.

In my opinion questions about preview- or beta-software are not inherently wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Use **too localized** when the usefulness and relevance of questions becomes obsolete as nobody would be [left working on the beta version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/how-do-you-keep-questions-about-beta-products-fresh) if the full fleshed product is out there. They only serve to clutter the search results and muddy the signal.

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

For speculative questions and those that grab at will anything about peering into the crystal ball, change it up between **not a real question**

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

or **not constructive**

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: But use "too localized" **until** the full fleshed product is out there and have replaced the beta.